# How to manage the combining of multiple REST API calls into one data model?

Tags: python, python-requests, pos

I'm learning to collect data from REST APIs to generate custom reports.

For example, one of the APIs I'm dealing with is the POS application [MobileBytes](https://api.mobilebytes.com/). For this API my goal is to model `daily sales > group by room > summarized by each category`.

A Daily Sales Report uses the debit credit model:

| Account | DR | CR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Credit Cards receivable | DR |  |
| Cash receivable | DR |  |
| Bar liquor |  | CR |
| Bar wine |  | CR |
| Bar beer |  | CR |
| Bar food |  | CR |
| Patio Food |  | CR |
| Patio liquor |  | CR |
| Patio wine |  | CR |
| Patio beer |  | CR |
| Sales Tax |  | CR |
| Tips |  | CR |

As this example of a Sales Report shows, the API's "rooms" represent the different physical areas in the establishment: `bar, patio` Other rooms could include: `dining, banquet, take-out, hrubgub, eberuats`. Report categories represent the common categories of sales used in food service accounting: `food, liquor, wine, beer`, and other categories could include: `dessert, retail`. The results of each API endpoint are a **variable length** array of features and their totals. The constraint of the debit-credit model is total debits equal total credits (just like any purchase receipt; total of your purchases + tax equal what you paid).

**And just in case** you thought it an easy job of querying each endpoint to collect each table for the final report--no--each record item *label* uses an `id` which points to the ***Setup API*** where the string representation or string label for each record item is found. Putting it all together `{"bar" : {"food": $x_1, "liquor":$x_2, "wine": $x_3, "beer": $x_4}, ..` is calling at least 3-4 different endpoints--two for each subsection of the sales report (ie. `rooms` and `categories`), plus one or more for their labels in the `setup` and `menu` endpoints.

***How could I manage, organize and combine all of these different API calls?***

I'm leaning towards using Pandas DataFrames as described in this example: [Query API’s with Json Output in Python (Medium article)](https://towardsdatascience.com/query-apis-with-json-output-in-python-5e16182a9df)

Comment: What's stopping you from parsing the JSON into a dataframe? Or adding an ORM library to your app? The "better" solution, IMO, would be to have a GraphQL endpoint, but I assume your server doesn't have that

Comment: ***"What's stopping you.."*** ??! I'm not prevented. Its just complicated combining these outputs. I hoped to learn of more efficient methods. ***"ORM library"*** care to recommend one? I asked specifically about this on Python Discord and was told ORMs are for databases.  ***"your server "*** You're correct, not my server; This is what is offered.

Comment: Just because you're using Discord doesn't mean you cannot use a sqlite (or external) database, which any ORM can work with, assuming that's what you want. There's no simple answer to this problem, and you've not shown any JSON data for us to help you further. You must parse both responses and do the merge yourself

Comment: > ***"do the merge yourself"*** _This!_ What exactly does that mean? Believe what I'm saying, this is the heart of the question. I gave an example for Pandas DataFrames.  Is that the best we can do? ***"you've not shown any JSON data"*** ??  I provided a link to the API's swagger documentation and listed two endpoints and a goal. Is swagger documentation not sufficient to communicate the _types_ of joins I need to make? That I'm not just pulling a completed report, but that this POS system's endpoints are just as I described--SQL like--with IDs which can only be filled from other endpoints.

Comment: For example, lets say you want the list `[1, 2, 3]` from getting one response with `[{"id: 1, "data": "foo"}]`, and another response `{"elements_by_id": {"1": [1, 2, 3]}}`... You need to loop over each object of the first, extract the `id==1`, then lookup the data in the second using something like `response2["elements_by_id"][response_one_id]`... We shouldn't be responsible for understanding what data  the Swagger API responds with. You should give an example yourself of what data you're trying to parse and create as output. There is no "best" way to do what you're asking

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be no actual ID for you to join against in the data.

You have a list of "report categories" and "rooms". Each with their own IDs. Each with their own `quantity`, for example.

It's also not clear what each object represents. Days? If so, create a simple loop over each day from start-to-end, then parse each object.

```
import requests
from datetime import date, timedelta

start = date(2022, 1, 21)
startDate = start.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
end = date(2022, 1, 22)
endDate= end.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

# TODO: You need to add API keys in here
sales_api = 'https://api.mobilebytes.com/v2/reports/sales'
categories = requests.get(f'{sales_api}/reportCategories/{startDate}/{endDate}')
rooms = requests.get(f'{sales_api}/rooms/{startDate}/{endDate}')

output = []  # to build your output for a dataframe

if categories.status_code // 100 == 2 and rooms.status_code // 100 == 2:
  # These lists should be the same size, so you can zip them
  c = categories.json()['application/json']
  r = rooms.json()['application/json']
  d = start
  for category, room in zip(c, r):
     print(d, category, room)  # For debugging

     # TODO: parse both objects and populate your list above
     output.append({
       'date': d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
       'category_id': category['report_category_id'],
       # TODO: parse more category values
       'room_id': room['room_id']
       # TODO: parse more room values
     })
     d += timedelta(days = 1)
else:
  raise Error('Unable to connect')
```

From a list of dictionaries, it is easy to create a dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(output)
```

Regarding ORM, you can use [`swagger-codegen`](https://swagger.io/tools/swagger-codegen/) to create Python classes that represent the documented response bodies.

Comment: Nice example from start to finish, and similar to an ORM.